# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod throws WebCmdletWebResponseException

Tags: powershell

I am trying the following command

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://serverIP/my/application/URL' -Method 'GET' -WebSession $CurrentSession
```

I tried it with `Invoke-WebRequest` as well But I am getting this error for both of them

```
Invoke-WebRequest : An unexpected error has occurred while attempting to serialize a Date datatype.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://serverIP/my/application/UR ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I am quite new at using the `Invoke-RestMethod`
Can someone please help me with this error?

Comment: You are using `Invoke-RestMethod`, but the error says `Invoke-WebRequest` ??

Comment: Yes, actually I tired both commands ```Invoke-RestMethod``` as well as ```Invoke-WebRequest``` but getting same error for both of them